# go from sign_in to user/:id with Devise in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using devise to make a web app and I have the route root `staticpages#index`(localhost:3000) where there are two links, log in (localhost:3000/users/sign_in) and sign up (`localhost:3000/users/sign_up`). My problem is that when I log in succesfully I want the page redirects me to (`localhost:3000/user/:id`) instead of the localhost:3000 again. I've been looking for help in internet and I've found one post where it said to put this in the `application_controller.rb`

**application_controller.rb**

```
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    @user= current_user
  end
```

But this doesn´t work. I show you my routes.rb just in case is the real problem, but I think is good.

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'staticpages#index'

  devise_for :users

  resources :users, only: [:show]

end
```

I hope someone could help me. Thank you in advance¡¡

Comment: [Have you seen the documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in)?

Answer (score 1):

It's been a bit since I've worked with Devise, but try this:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  user_path(current_user)
end
```

Comment: It's not working. It keeps sending me to localhost:3000 but I'm not sure if the problema is in other place or if I'm missin something else. Thank you anyway